# Changing the Heaviside function at origin

Tags: matlab

is there any way to change the value of heaviside function at zero in matlab 2014b? because I have to change the value from 0.5 to 1.

Comment: You could make your own, if you change it then it's not really the Heaviside function anymore...

Comment: actually in the litrature the value of heaviside(0) = 1 is used for continuous functions. since my function is continuous I would like to use one as heaviside (0)

Comment: Even still, just make your own...

Comment: If I want to make my own step function, how can I define it's derivative and its integral?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `'HeavisideAtOrigin'` preference of `sympref` to set a custom value at the origin:

```
sympref('HeavisideAtOrigin',1);
one = heaviside(-1:1)
sympref('HeavisideAtOrigin',0.5);
pointFive= heaviside(-1:1)

...

one =

     0     1     1


pointFive =

         0    0.5000    1.0000
```

---

The above was [introduced in R2015a](http://se.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/whatsnew.html). For pre-R2015a, you'll have to build your own fix for this, e.g.:

```
% heavisideOrigin1.m
function y = heavisideOrigin1(x)
    y = round(heaviside(x));
end

% ...
y = heavisideOrigin1(-1:1)

% prints
y =

     0     1     1
```

Comment: This is not possible in matlab 2014b

Comment: My bad, didn't realize this was [introduced only in R2015a](http://se.mathworks.com/products/symbolic/whatsnew.html). I'll update with a custom fix for pre-2015a.

Comment: so, is there any solutions?

Comment: @MsenRezaee See one example of a custom solution added below the original answer above.

Comment: @MsenRezaee Happy to help.